# How to generate access token for youtube api?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to integrate Youtube API into my project but to start working with it, I need to generate the access token. I searched the internet and found multiple articles that confused me a lot. I have seen various methods to generate it, but none of them works for me.
I also tried this [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library#oauth2), but this gives me the following error:

```
code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'The request is not properly authorized.',
      domain: 'youtube.activity',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ]
```

I am tired of searching more on this, so if anyone has any idea to get it, Please tell me. It will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to follow the official documentation? There are clear steps on how to get access.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#before-you-start